# Drop Cap Style not working in Firefox

Tags: css

My drop cap style is working in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Any reason why? Thanks!

```
.summary:first-letter {
    float:left;
    color:#D4D4C7;
    font-size:44px;
    line-height:35px;
    padding-top:3px; 
    padding-right:3px;
    font-family: Times, serif, Georgia;
}
```

Comment: It works in FF for me. I'm using v29 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax should have two colons after `.summary` and not just one.

```
.summary::first-letter {
    float:left;
    color:#D4D4C7;
    font-size:44px;
    line-height:35px;
    padding-top:3px; 
    padding-right:3px;
    font-family: Times, serif, Georgia;
}
```

Try that and see if that works. If you are using an older FF browser, that may be the issue. The single colon is usually used for [IE8 support](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/).

Comment: @user3263446 Make sure to mark this as the answer if this corrected your issue. Glad to help!